# What is the default parameter type in .net core web api?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

For example, I have an API like this:

```
[HttpPost("device")]
public string Post(string uid, string name)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Will this code I posted work? By default?

`form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `raw`?

I know If I want to post json data I have to add the `[FromBody]` and the parameter into a class right?

Question 2: how to post json data to the API, but do not have to use a instance of the parameter but can use the parameter?

```
string uid, string deviceId
```

Comment: How is it going on sir? Is there any further issue?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: I newly created an asp.net core 3.1 api project and create a new `HomeController`, and it worked in my side

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("device")]
        public string Post(string uid, string name)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Q2: I think there might be some way to realize your goal but I'm afraid that needs more configuration such as adding a middleware. So I'm afraid the easiest way to receive json data is using an entity which contains the parameters. And if you consists on not creating entity for that data format, maybe you can use `Dictionary` like code below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("device")]
        public string Post([FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> test)
        {
            string uid = test.GetValueOrDefault("uid");
            string name = test.GetValueOrDefault("name");
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]